# Is Using MySql Connector/C++ necessary in order to access/change mysql database?

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

If I have to download Connector would I also need to download it on any computer I want to use the C++ application on? I haven't started any code for the database part yet but I'm writing an application that reads data and I want to store that in a mysql database using C++.

Comment: An SQlite database can be a good choice. It's small, fast and free - it also has the large benefit of not requiring installation - just statically link it or include the sqlite.dll file with your exe file and you're good to go - nothing stopping it run on a usb stick in any computer you throw it at. Using the ODBC route to whichever database you choose to use is well worth the effort - it then becomes entirely trivial to use the same data stored in any one of a bunh of different database engines - you often just need to change the connection string - something to consider, anyway.

Comment: I will look at that as it seems I would have to buy a GPL license which means I will need to open source my code as well and other implications (I think).

Comment: Hmm. I'm no legal expert by any means, though I was under the impression that SQLite is released to the public domain and as such, you're more-or-less free to do with it as you please. The following quote from their site appears to agree: `Anyone is free to copy, modify, publish, use, compile, sell, or distribute the original SQLite code, either in source code form or as a compiled binary, for any purpose, commercial or non-commercial, and by any means.` Source: https://sqlite.org/copyright.html - I'm don't think you even have to acknowledge its usage, let alone share source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is Using MySql Connector/C++ necessary in order to access/change mysql database?

You don't have to connect to the official MySQL connector. You can use [ODBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Database_Connectivity) or other custom connectors.

> If I have to download Connector would I also need to download it on any computer I want to use the C++ application on?

It depends whether you link to the MySQL connector library statically or dynamically.

- Linking statically is achieved by linking against the static MySQL connector library, usually named `libmysqlcppconn-static.a` (or `.lib` on windows), and will allow you to run your program on environments where the mysql connector is not installed.
- Linking dynamically is achieved by linking against the dynamic MySQL connector library, usually named `libmysqlcppconn.so` (or `.dll` on windows, `.dylib` on macOS), and will require your program to run on environments where the mysql connector has been installed.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993390/static-linking-vs-dynamic-linking) discusses the tradeoffs of static vs. dynamic linking in more details.

[This questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817842/accessing-mysql-through-c) discusses the licensing implications of using MysQL connector.

Comment: My application needs to be usable on computers other than mine which is why I was asking. Thanks.

Comment: So to use the Mysql connector in the first place I would have to open source my code and buy a GPL license, just to clarify? I'm a bit new to the licensing and what the implications are. I will definitely have a look at ODBC though and will probably use that instead.